# Not able to Encrypt Azure CloudFile. Was able to Encrypt Azure Blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I am not able to find any class or library to Encrypt/Decrypt Azure CloudFile using C#.
I am searching for something which is available for Azure CloudFile.

Following link explain about Blob,but I need similar for CloudFiles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?tabs=dotnet

I need something like below, but for ColudFile.

```
        BlobEncryptionPolicy policy
           = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);

        BlobRequestOptions options
           = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
```

Any help guys.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to encrypt/decrypt data in AzureStorage.file . As only Blob, Queue and Table support encryption policy .

**Reference:**  [Client-Side Encryption with .NET for Microsoft Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption?tabs=dotnet11)

**Reference for cloud file library:** [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File Namespace - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)